# jqgrid export to excell. add data not only from table

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In jqgrid there is perfect function: exportToExcel. It works fine. I wonder if there are some options to add to exported file additional columns or data not from table, but my custom data.

Comment: Should I think that you use Guriddo jqGrid? What for a custom data should be added - new column(s), new row(s) or a existing data should be modified?

Comment: @TonyTomov, yes. I need to add new row above the exported table in excell with my custom data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you for the question it is very useful.

In order to do the requested job you will need first to download the latest build of [Guriddo jqGrid from GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/archive/master.zip)

To do the job you will need to use the onBeforeExport event in exportToExcel method with the code like this:

```
$("#export").on("click", function(){
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel",{
        ...
        onBeforeExport : function ( xlsx, rowPos ) {
            // rowPos is the last inserted index with data in the excel sheet

            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

            // function to add a row
            function Addrow(index, data) {
                var row = sheet.createElement('row');
                row.setAttribute("r", index);
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var key = data[i].key;
                    var value = data[i].value;
                    var c  = sheet.createElement('c');

                    c.setAttribute("t", "inlineStr");
                    //c.setAttribute("s", "2"); This make it bold
                    c.setAttribute("r", key + index);

                    var is = sheet.createElement('is');
                    var t = sheet.createElement('t');
                    var text = sheet.createTextNode(value)

                    t.appendChild(text);                                      
                    is.appendChild(t);
                    c.appendChild(is);
                    row.appendChild(c);                                                                                                                         
                }

                return row;
            }
            var r1 = Addrow(++rowPos, [{ key: 'A', value: rowPos }, { key: 'B', value: 'Product1' }]);
            var r2 = Addrow(++rowPos, [{ key: 'A', value: rowPos }, { key: 'B', value: 'Product2' }]);                          
            var r3 = Addrow(++rowPos, [{ key: 'A', value: rowPos }, { key: 'B', value: 'Product3' }]);
            var r4 = Addrow(++rowPos, [{ key: 'A', value: rowPos }, { key: 'B', value: 'Product4' }]);
            // get sheetData
            var sheetData = sheet.getElementsByTagName('sheetData')[0];

            sheetData.insertBefore(r4,sheetData.childNodes[0]);
            sheetData.insertBefore(r3,sheetData.childNodes[0]);
            sheetData.insertBefore(r2,sheetData.childNodes[0]);
            sheetData.insertBefore(r1,sheetData.childNodes[0]);                 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Tony! You saved my day.

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you